# Include Perl class file

Tags: perl, oop, class, include, require

I have a Perl class file (package): person.pl

```
package person;

sub create {
  my $this = {  
    name => undef,
    email => undef
  }

  bless $this;
  return $this;
}  

1;
```

and i need to use this class in another file: test.pl

(note that person.pl and test.pl are in the same directory)

```
require "person.pl";

$john_doe = person::create();
$john_doe->{name} = "John Doe";
$john_doe->{email} = "johndoe@example.com";
```

but it didn't come to success.

I'm using XAMPP to run both PHP & Perl.

I think it doesn't seem right to use "require" to get
the code of the class 'person', but i don't know
how to resolve this problem. Please help...

Comment: Hello nicola, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to familiarise yourself with the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) about code formatting.

Comment: You should start the name of all your packages with a capital letter.  The Perl conventions are that modules start with a capital and pragmatics are all lowercase to tell them apart at a glance.

Comment: @shawn: people like that convention, however, i often do the inverted way. my_class_name, and, My_Instance_Name. My convention comes from natural human language, like 'software_engineer' is the class name, and 'John Smith' is a 'software_engineer', it just seems more natural. And i usually use this convention for my project. a little bit weird. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you should name the file person.pm (for Perl Module).  Then you can load it with the [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) function:

```
use person;
```

If the directory where person.pm is located is not in `@INC`, you can use the [lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib) pragma to add it:

```
use lib 'c:/some_path_to_source_dir';
use person;
```

Secondly, Perl doesn't have special syntax for constructors.  You named your constructor `create` (which is ok, but non-standard), but then tried to call `person::new`, which doesn't exist.

If you're going to be doing object-oriented programming in Perl, you should really look at [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose).  Among other things, it creates the constructor for you.

If you don't want to use Moose, here are some other improvements you can make:

```
package person;

use strict;   # These 2 lines will help catch a **lot** of mistakes
use warnings; # you might make.  Always use them.

sub new {            # Use the common name
  my $class = shift; # To allow subclassing

  my $this = {  
    name => undef;
    email => undef;
  }

  bless $this, $class; # To allow subclassing
  return $this;
}
```

Then call the constructor as a class method:

```
use strict;   # Use strict and warnings in your main program too!
use warnings;
use person;

my $john_doe = person->new();
```

Note: It's more common in Perl to use `$self` rather than `$this`, but it doesn't actually matter.  Perl's built-in object system is very minimal and places few restrictions on how you use it.

Comment: but the line "use person;" causes error. it (perl over apache) says "not found person.pm in @INC blah blah...", and i need 'person.pl' (or 'person.pm') to be in the same directory with 'test.pl'

Comment: thanks a lot for those comments on the code, i really treasure those comments, however, the main matter is how to load a perl source file from another perl file which are located in the same directory

Comment: @users: refer to nicola's answer below for the dynamic module loading (works best when module source code is under development)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem of loading Perl source files from another Perl file in the same directory. Normally you would:

```
use lib "c:/some_dir_path";
use class_name;
```

The solution below is better when the module's source code is under development, as it reloads the module in Perl's cache. It ensures the reloading of class source code each time it requires, meaning any change in the source code of the to-be-included file will effect each time the file is included in compilation or in runtime:

```
push (@INC,"c:/some_path_to_source_dir"); #directory contains perl source files

delete @INC{"class1.pl"}; #to reload class1
require "class1.pl";

delete @INC{"class2.pl"}; #to reload class2
require "class2.pl";

delete @INC{"class3.pl"}; #to reload class3
require "class3.pl";
```

I don't know whether it's a good way, please correct me.

Comment: cjm provides the answer - of course you are free to ignore it.

Comment: 1) It is better to `use lib 'path'` rather than `push @INC, 'path'`. 2) You shouldn't need to "reload" your modules; lose the `delete` statements. 3) Normal practice is to use `.pl` only for executable scripts; modules (OO or otherwise) are better named with `.pm`, which also allows you to use `use` rather than `require` to load them.

Comment: @reinierpost: yes, that helped me a lot in understanding basic OOP in perl

Comment: @dave: but the module file (.pm) is my own library and it is under development, i need to reload (refresh in perl cache) each time i run the main code file. Of course when my module has no more modification, I should definitely use [use lib 'path'].